# Ubuntu extracts an EMPTY FOLDER? File Manager Issue

Tags: error-handling, unzip

```
bekepart@bekepart-System-Product-Name:~/Downloads$ unzip cucc.zip -d /home/bekepart/Desktop
Archive:  cucc.zip
creating: /home/bekepart/Desktop/cucc/
creating: /home/bekepart/Desktop/cucc/gyak5/
creating: /home/bekepart/Desktop/cucc/gyak5/gverem/
extracting: /home/bekepart/Desktop/cucc/gyak5/gverem/integer_vermek.ads  
inflating: /home/bekepart/Desktop/cucc/gyak5/gverem/megfordit.adb
```

etc.etc puts many lines of this kind of stuff but on my desktop I end up with an empty "cucc" folder.

**edit:** thank you for the comments, I tried a few things, seems like the extraction actually happens(ls shows the files) so i guessed its an updating issue, i pressed F5 in the file manager, and voilá there are the files.

I repeated the process out of curiosity, and it again forgot to update the "file explorer" no matter how many times i reopen that file explorer window("cucc"). From now on i should press F5 every time i visit a folder(?) I guess its really something for the OS to do. Any idea, what causes the problem?

Comment: Can you extract it using GUI?

Comment: Please open a terminal and run the command `ls ~/Desktop/cucc/` Also, any error messages at the end of the extraction?

Comment: You can upload **all** the output (from the **beginning** to the **end**) in [this site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and then link the *resulting link* here.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved it by showing hidden files in file explorer.

[image: screenshot of right-clicking and clicking Show Hidden Files]

This can be done by right-clicking and clicking Show Hidden Files or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

The hidden files did not work for me. I could not find a solution, so I used a workaround.

When you click on the archive and then use the extract button to extract it works. You should use "extract selected folders option" and select the folders. I have not tried with "extract all files".

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.5

It seems the problem was present after updating(not from a different version of Ubuntu). I have not confirmed this, I am guessing on nothing about this part.